# JSP cannot find default bundle for i18n

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, intellij-idea, internationalization

After browsing through the whole internet I ended up asking this question, although I find it a bit difficult to describe the situation.

I have a little application here which runs on embedded Tomcat server (v7), and uses servlets and JSPs; I try to internationalize them with JSTL  tags. The final project is deployed as JAR, and when I run it from the console with `java -jar`, the embedded server starts nicely, everything works just fine.

**The problem is** when I try to run it in the IDE (I use IntelliJ Idea v13.1.2): again, it starts, but instead of the values from the bundle, the pages show values such as ???default.username???.

Here is how my JSPs mostly look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="language"
   value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}"
   scope="session"/>
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="messages" scope="session" var="bund"/>

<html>
<head>
    <title><fmt:message bundle="${bund}" key="default.title" /></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/tdb.css" media="all">
</head>
```

And so on. The `<fmt:message bundle="${bund}" key="default.title" />` and similar parts work perfectly fine when I use the JAR, and result in ???default.title??? when from IDE. In one case I use the bundle file from the servlet, and when ran from JAR, it works fine, and when from IDE, it causes `java.util.MissingResourceException`.

**What have I tried so far?** I added my messages.properties and messages_en_US.properties files in various locations (in resources folder, on the same level with the java and webapp folders; in separate package in the com.my.example package; as simple properties files in the com.my.example package), tried to refer to it only with the basename (`resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale);`), or with the fully qualified path; also, I set the fallbackLocale and localizationContext parameters in the web.xml file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks well.

I was checking in some of my projects and I have this attributes:

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="org.juanitodread.msg.label" var="label"/>


<fmt:message key="common.title" bundle="${label}" />
```

I have my projects in Eclipse, but you can try without "scope" attribute. My label.properties file is in "org.juanitodread.msg" package.

Comment: I tried with and without scope, with and without the longer path, and none of the solutions worked. But thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I also use the Intellij Idea and had the similar problems, here are my conclusions. You should put your 'messages file' to

```
yourproject/src/main/java/resources
```

folder (as a rule, Idea will highlight the resources folder icon with the specified sign). I have no fallback locale configuration and localization context parameters in web.xml. My bundle file is named **messages_en.properties** and I use it the way

```
<fmt:setBundle basename="messages" var="labels" />
```

and not add "resources.messages" to basename attribute.
I'm running IntellijIdea version 2016.2, and my application works fine on:

- embedded Tomcat v 7.0.73 , using bmuschko gradle-tomcat plugin https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin
- remote Tomcat v 7.0.73 deployment with Tomcat Server Idea configuration

To check your resources are really loading (if your properties are not loaded to the page that means you're obviously missing the file), use the following code, as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4137991/2759640

```
ClassLoader ctxLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
URL propsURL = ctxLoader.getResource("opto-mapping.properties");
URLConnection propsConn = propsURL.openConnection();
```

In case you have your resources loaded, **openConnecton** will throw an exception, that connection to the messages.properties has been already opened (at least I've done that way and tried to make my bundle work also for a long time).