# NoSuchMessageException - Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am changing from `ResourceBundleMessageSource` to `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`.

I have changed my app-dispatcher-servlet.xml to reflect the requirements of ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.  From `<value>com.app.properties.windows</value>` to `<value>classpath:windows</value>`  But I am getting `NoSuchMEssageException`. I suspect it has to do with where I put my properties files or I am not linking it right.

Doc:

> It follows the basic ResourceBundle rule
>   of not specifying file extension or language codes, but can refer to
>   any Spring resource location (instead of being restricted to classpath
>   resources). With a "classpath:" prefix, resources can still be loaded
>   from the classpath, but "cacheSeconds" values other than "-1" (caching
>   forever) might not work reliably in this case.

Below is what I have....

[image: Folder structure]
messages_en_US.properties

```
NotBlank.book.name = Enter something don't be lazy
```

app-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:messages</value>
            <value>classpath:windows</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

</bean>

// some i18n and localization bean
```

Stack Trace

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found
>   under code 'Size.book.ispn' for locale 'zh_CN'.
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause
>
> org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found
>   under code 'Size.book.ispn' for locale 'zh_CN'.
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:159)
>     com.app.controller.spaController.pageSpa(spaController.java:54)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
>     org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

The code that executes is in the controller

```
public class someController(){   
@autowired
private MEssageSource messageSource;

public String pageSpa(Model model){
    System.out.println("loading index page");

    //System.out.println(((CustomMessageSource) messageSource).listMessageProperties("book", locale));
    Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("NotBlank.book.name", null, locale));

    return "spa";
}
```

Thank you

Comment: can you share the stack trace and the code that reads the message

Comment: I have added stack trace

Comment: I think you should put message resource files into the resource folder under WEB-INF, it should be there by default.

Comment: have you tried my answer below?

Comment: @VPK the doc: but can refer to any Spring resource location (instead of being restricted to classpath resources).  I would think with Reloadable.... it shouldn't matter.  Unless I am miss understanding the doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I end up doing is this

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="com.app.service.CustomMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:com/app/properties/messages</value>
            <value>classpath:com/app/properties/windows</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

</bean>
```

Since classpath:  contains WEB-INF/class.  I just explicitly included the actual class path to my properties files.

I am not sure why following the doc doesn't work. But this worked for me. Hope this helped others from days of agony.

Answer (score 1):

What works for me is the following
Move your message files under WEB-INF

Change the configurations as following

```
<bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>WEB-INF/messages</value>
            <value>WEB-INF/windows</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I tried to use classpath prefix as indicated in the documentation but it did not work

See also: [Reloading of properties file which is loaded using setBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136403/reloading-of-properties-file-which-is-loaded-using-setbundle)

Comment: Thanks... let me try this.. Correct me if I am wrong classpath:  contains WEB-INF/class.  Is this correct? I just don't see why its not working....

Comment: Class path contains WEB-INF/class. In general I failed to use classpath: but  I think that only WEB-INF is reload-bale in tomcat anyway